# Title in proc print sas EG

Tags: sas

I am ending my project in SAS EG. This project create some Statement by selecting data with Prompt variables. There are:

```
%let variable1 = name1
%let variable2 = name2
%let variable3 = name3
```

The final proc print code is:

```
proc print data = mydata;
title "This statement created with &variable1 &variable2 &variable3"
```

But there is a situation where for exaple variable3 isn't present in a code at all. Than after execution I will get:

```
"This statement created with name1 name2 &variable3"
```

Is there is any way to avoid it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the proc print in a macro and check if the variable exists:

```
%macro m;
proc print data = mydata;

title "This statement created with "
%if %Symexist(variable1) %then "&variable1 ";
%if %Symexist(variable2) %then "&variable2 ";
%if %Symexist(variable3) %then "&variable3";;
run;
%mend;
%m;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your macro variables in a %Global or %Local statement (depending on your needs).

```
%Global VARIABLE1 VARIABLE2 VARIABLE3;

%Let VARIABLE1=name1;
%Let VARIABLE2=name2;
/*%Let VARIABLE3=name3;*/

title "This statement created with &variable1 &variable2 &variable3";
Proc print data=sashelp.cars(obs=1); run;
```